# How do I set Automatic Updates on Azure DevTest Lab VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I have a Windows VM set up in a Azure DevTest lab running Windows Server 2016, based on the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Gallery Image. This is serving as a Custom Build Agent for VSTS.

I cannot find how to set it to automatically apply Windows Updates.

I found this article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0a46b8ac-0b16-4b87-a881-260c8d5609f7/disabling-windows-update-via-group-policy?forum=winserverGP but the Wuau.admin template does not exist on the server.

This article https://www.rootusers.com/configure-automatic-updates-for-windows-server-2016/ references the Group Policy Editor tool in Server Manager...but the Azure VM doesn't have that as a tool in Server Manager. Nor does the local GPE have the Group Policy Management section in the tree view as shown in the article.

I am probably missing something very simple, but I'm not really that familiar with server management. My goal is to get the VM set up so that it keeps itself patched and running smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sconfig to set the Windows Updates settings to automatic

> Change your Windows Update Settings
>
> To change your Windows Update Settings with SCONFIG, follow these steps: 
>   •Open a command prompt with Admin permissions. 
>   •Type sconfig and press Enter. 
>   ◦NOTE: There may be a short pause as the tool inspects your system.
>
> •Press 5 and then Enter. This will bring up the following options for you to choose from: 
>   ◦(A)utomatic – This will configure your machine to automatically scan, download, install and reboot after applying any updates. 
>   ◦(D)ownloadOnly – This will automatically scan, download and notify the admin if updates need to be installed. This is the default setting on Windows Server 2016. 
>   ◦(M)anual — This turns Automatic Updates off. Your system will never check for updates.
>
> •Press the letter specified in the “( )” and press Enter to apply.
>
> •When the tool applies the configuration you have selected, you will see a message pop-up similar to the one below. Click the OK button to dismiss the message. The tool will refresh the menu and option 5 will now show the new configuration.

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/10/25/__trashed/

Edit based on comment of derape

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16690477)

Comment: Thanks @derape for your comment, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That got them enabled. It also led me to how to set a time other than 3:00AM by using the local Group Policy editor...which once I found it was a better way to set it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328010/how-to-configure-automatic-updates-by-using-group-policy-or-registry-s